# Outline mixed alphabetic and numeric counters in CSS

Tags: css, nested, counter

I am looking for the SIMPLEST, ELEGANT, SCALABLE, and RECURSIVE CSS code to obtain a  list like this one:

```
A1 Matilda
A2 Giorgio
   B1 Luisa
   B2 Giovanni
      C1 Anna
      C2 Francesco
         D1 Giorgio
         D2 Marco
            E1 Luigi
            E2 Giovanna
            E3 Maria
         D3 Ernesto
      C3 Benedetta
   B3 Annabella
A3 Stefano
```

By recursive I mean that I do not want to assume that I have a specific number of nesting levels, not to create a lot of different counters to associate to classes, because that would make the list hard to maintain in case of changes.

So I wrote the following CSS code

```
.tree { }
.tree ul {list-style: none; }
.tree ul li { }
.tree ul li:before { margin: 0 0.5rem 0 0; }

.tree { counter-reset: alpha; }
.tree ul { counter-increment: alpha; counter-reset: number; }
.tree ul li:before { counter-increment: number; content: counter(alpha,upper-alpha) counter(number); }
```

for the following HTML code

```
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>Matilda</li>
    <li>Giorgio
      <ul>
        <li>Luisa</li>
        <li>Giovanni
          <ul>
            <li>Anna</li>
            <li>Francesco
              <ul>
                <li>Giorgio</li>
                <li>Marco
                  <ul>
                    <li>Luigi</li>
                    <li>Giovanna</li>
                    <li>Maria</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Ernesto</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Benedetta</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Annabella</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Stefano</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but I get

```
A1 Matilda
A2 Giorgio
   B1 Luisa
   B2 Giovanni
      C1 Anna
      C2 Francesco
         D1 Giorgio
         D2 Marco
            E1 Luigi
            E2 Giovanna
            E3 Maria
         E3 Ernesto
      E3 Benedetta
   E3 Annabella
E3 Stefano
```

Any idea how to obtain what I wish WITHOUT assuming a specific nesting level (e.g. 5).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A bit off topic as this will not solve your problem, but these lists are clearly ordered so you might want to consider `<ol>` over `<ul>` :-)

Comment: I don't think this is possible because the `alpha` counter will increment for **every** `<ul>` (nested or not) unless you're specifying the list level. By the time you are "coming back" out of the nested `<ul>` elements, the `alpha` counter is up to E, in your example, and cannot be decremented.